# DolphinDB equivalent for SQL ORDER BY with NULLS LAST

Tags: null, sql-order-by, dolphindb

I want NULL values to be returned after non-NULL values when sorting in ascending order in SQL query, like `NULLS LAST` supported in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

By default, NULL values are treated as the minimum value of a data type, so they always come first when sorted in ascending order. Therefore, to make them come last, you should define the NULL value as the maximum value of the field using `nullFill`. For example:

```
t=table(1 5 3 NULL 6 NULL 7 8 4 NULL as id)
select * from t order by nullFill(id,2147483647)
```

Return:

```
id
1
3
4
5
6
7
8
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

However, there is a limitation: there cannot be any data type higher than the NULL value in this column. In this case, you can convert the type of the field to a more precise one. For example:

```
t=table(1 5 3 NULL 2147483647 NULL 7 8 NULL as id)
select * from t order by nullFill(long(id),2147
```